# Сложение результата после каждого вызова рекурсивной функции

Tags: python

Функция возвращает количество совпавших слов по типу игры в слова. Как сделать так, чтобы переменная count после каждого вызова функции необнулялась и складывала новый результат с результатом предыдущего вызова функции?

```
def string_concatenation(line):
    global count
    count = 0

    if len(line) == 0:
        print("Cтрока пуста")
        return

    words = line.split()
    if words[0][-1] == words[1][0:1]:
        count = count + len(words[0]+words[1])
        print(count)
        words.remove(words[0])
        new_line = ' '.join(words)
        string_concatenation(new_line)
    else:
        print("Нету совпадения")
        return

s = "Собака азот томат теплоход дача арбуз забота такси"
string_concatenation(s)
```

Comment: Вынеси строку count = 0 за пределы функции

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В Питоне нельзя передать переменную статического типа по ссылке, но можно использовать паллиативное решение: список из одного элемента, так как коллекции, напротив, передаются только по ссылке.

   ```
   def string_concatenation(line, count):
       if len(line) > 0:
           words = line.split()
           if len(words)>1:
               if words[0][-1] == words[1][0:1]:
                   count[0] = count[0] + 1
               words.remove(words[0])
               new_line = ' '.join(words)
               string_concatenation(new_line, count)
           else:
               if count[0]>0:
                   count[0] = count[0] + 1

        s = "Собака азот томат теплоход дача арбуз забота такси"
        count=[0]
        string_concatenation(s, count)
        print(count)
   ```
2. Так же можно получить и замкнутое рекурсивное решение. Проблема в том, что при нахождении первой пары у нас количество слов не 1, а два. Решить ее можно сначала сохранив значение функции в переменную, а потом увеличив его на 1 в нужный момент (хвостовая рекурсия)

   ```
   def string_concatenation2(line):
       if len(line) > 0:
           words = line.split()
           if len(words)>1:
               count=0
               if words[0][-1] == words[1][0:1]:
                   count = 1
               words.remove(words[0])
               new_line = ' '.join(words)
               res=string_concatenation2(new_line)+count
               if res==1:
                   res=2
               return res
           else:
               return 0
       else:
           return 0


       print(string_concatenation2(s))
   ```
3. Кроме того, вы считали не количество слов, а их суммарную длину
4. Не нужно в функцию засовывать все возможные действия. Она у вас считает количество слов - пусть и считает. А все остальное нужно сделать с возвращаемым значением. Например так:

   ```
   result=string_concatenation2(s)

   if result>0:
        print('Слов= ', result)
   else:
        print('Нет совпадающих слов')
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1 способ. Вынести переменную count за пределы функции, тогда она будет глобальной по отношению к телу и при новом вызове функции не будет обнуляться (соответственно убери в теле функции строку count = 0;

2 способ. Передавай в функцию не только строку, но и некоторый флаг "first_call": string_concatenation(line, first_call). Если он равен true, то есть это первый вызов, то обнули count, и тут-же присвой переменной first_call значение  false. При следующем рекурентном вызове функции переменная count обнуляться не будет уже.

Comment: Не флаг, а саму переменную счетчик

Comment: Обнуляться не будет но и определенна не будет. Попробуйте написать код.